# Ordering Meetings Fields For SuiteCRM Calendar

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

In the SuiteCRM calendar the default for Meetings is to show the SUBJECT of the Meeting followed by the MEETING OBJECTIVES.

I want to modify it so that on the first line it shows the MEETING OBJECTIVES and the second line is the SUBJECT of the Meeting.

I've looked in modules/Calendar and modules/Meetings and I'm still a bit lost. Any idea on which file I need to modify to be able to change the order of these two fields?

Comment: Are you sure "Meeting Objectives" isn't a custom field?

Comment: Hello. It is a Custom Field.  It turns out the Calendar isn't actually showing our meeting objectives which as you say is a custom field.  It's showing the default "status" field which defaults to "Customer Visit" So I guess I need to work out how to replace the "Status" field with out own "custom field" and also then change the order of the subject, and the "custom field" which is replacing "status".  I'm trying to get my head around CalendarDisplay.php thinking it must be from there and it uses Cal.js to display it? But i'm hoping it's something relatively easy in calendardisplay.php

Comment: Have you tried adjusting field display and order via Studio?

Comment: Hi Karl. Yes I've tried changing the order in studio, and that's great for creating the meetings it can now put the reason for the meeting first and the subject second. but that doesn't change the layout of the calender view that's grabbing the data and i just need to work out which of those files in the calendar module i guess grab them

Comment: OK... So part way there...modules/Meetings/metadata/additionalDetails.php

copying this to

custom/modules/Meetings/metadata and editing it to include my custom modules means now if you click on the "i" next to a calendar meeting in the extra details it shows the custom field so that's correct. Now it's trying to find where it stores it in the normal calendar entry to edit it there.

Comment: In the end it was all in the cal.js file

Answer (score 0):

Calendar module files are placed inside "`modules/Calendar`" folder. It contain tpl,js and php classes and functions for calendar module. "`get_activities`" function inside "`modules/Calendar/CalendarActivity.php`" actually load activities. You can change text here before it assigned to tpl/js file.
Further more you can also do changes inside this file: "`modules/Calendar/Calendar.php`" , see function "`load_activities`"

I think changing in JS should be last option because that is to complex and changes there need more time then doing it in alternative way in PHP file.